# How to use internationalization in Label fields in Screens in Oracle Policy Automation

Tags: internationalization, oracle-policy-automation

I am very new to Oracle Policy Automation. I am developing a screen which will give the option to the user to select languages. Based on his/her selection, the next screen should display a welcome message in the language selected.

I have two properties files (one for each language) and I have placed them inside the /classes/configuration folder.

Now, my query is how to invoke these properties files based on user selection and what should I write in the label field so that the messages are dynamically picked up.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may have figured this out by now.
In OPA the locale has to be set at the start of an interactive session (part of the start investigation URL) and cannot be changed subsequently. The locale specific resource files under configuration will then be used.
Your locale selection screen would probably need to be outside of OPA triggering a session start of the correct type. If you are using OWD then it will actually provide it's own locale selection screen if you try to access a rulebase without specifying the locale to use. We are working on some additional tooling around OWD to make this process a lot more [straightforward](http://monadsolutions.com)